# postgres database: When does a job get killed

Tags: python, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using a postgres database with sql-alchemy and flask. I have a couple of jobs which I have to run through the entire database to updates entries. When I do this on my local machine I get a very different behavior compared to the server. 
E.g. there seems to be an upper limit on how many entries I can get from the database?
On my local machine I just query all elements, while on the server I have to query 2000 entries step by step.
If I have too many entries the server gives me the message 'Killed'.
I would like to know
1. Who is killing my jobs (sqlalchemy, postgres)?
2. Since this does seem to behave differently on my local machine there must be a way to control this. Where would that be?
thanks
carl

Comment: Do you run your sqlalchemy code on server? Where do you see "Killed"? Can you run the query with psql and not get killed?

Comment: I am running a python script which I think is very difficult to run in psq... I get a killed on the terminal... no other error message

Answer (score 3):

Just the message "killed" appearing in the terminal window usually means the kernel was running out of memory and killed the process as an emergency measure.

Most libraries which connect to PostgreSQL will read the entire result set into memory, by default.  But some libraries have a way to tell it to process the results row by row, so they aren't all read into memory at once.  I don't know if flask has this option or not.

Perhaps your local machine has more available RAM than the server does (or fewer demands on the RAM it does have), or perhaps your local machine is configured to read from the database row by row rather than all at once.

Comment: Yes I agree that it might be a memory issue on the server, but the problem is that I get the 'killed' message also with other script which do not have a high memory demand... I would like to know how to investigate who is killing my jobs. thanks carl

Comment: That is OS specific.  I'd start by checking kernel logs in /var/log , and use 'top' sorting by mem ('M' command, on my top)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely kernel is killing your Python script. Python can have horrible memory usage.

I have a feeling you are trying to do these 2000 entry batches in a loop in one Python process. Python does not release all used memory, so the memory usage grows until it gets killed. (You can watch this with `top` command.)

You should try adapting your script to process 2000 records in a step and then quit. If you run in multiple times, it should continue where it left off. Or, a better option, try using [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) and run each job in separate worker. Run the jobs serially and let them die, when they finish. This way they will release the memory back to OS when they exit.

Comment: is there no way in python to force the release of memory?

Comment: It is - to quit the process.